# Handler function doesn't call the webservices

Tags: android, web-services, android-handler

```
    final int delayTime = 20000;

    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String Refresh_Location;
            Refresh_Location = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + "" + currentLatitude + "," + currentLongitude;
            Log.e("Refresh Location", "--->" + Refresh_Location);

           new SendLiveLatLong().execute();
            handler.postDelayed(this, delayTime);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayTime);
```

I used this function to call my webservices for every 20 sec. But it will not work properly and did not call that webservices every time.

Comment: It should execute only once after 20 sec. What have you done to execute "every" 20 sec? Post full code.

Comment: i want to call  new SendLiveLatLong().execute(); after every 20 sec. Which is my webservices.

Comment: post SendLiveLatLong code

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and replace Handler with Timer and use TimerTask instead of runnable.
Now everything is fine.

Comment: I tried it with timer also .                                                                          Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String Refresh_Location;
                Refresh_Location = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + "" + currentLatitude + "," + currentLongitude;
                Log.e("Refresh Location", "--->" + Refresh_Location);

                new SendLiveLatLong().execute();

            }
        }, 20000);
But it still didnt working.

Comment: Actually it is working properly after every 20 sec and dislay the log but doesnt call that webservices every time.